# Is it possible to two have pacakage name in a same folder in golang

Tags: go

I am a new person to golang.

Basically in node.js i used to organise my general functions like i will put in

```
lib/
  validation.js
  convert.js
  ..
```

Likewise i will organize.
I need to do the same here..

I tried like

```
lib/
 validation.go ( package name validator )
 convert.go ( package name converter )
```

and in the main.go which is present at the root level of my src folder
i import like `"./lib"` it works only if both package name is same else it throws error.

since i need separate names to call those function i cant give same packages coz of readability.

so basically i can create another folder in lib and with different Package name i can give.
This is the option available or some other possibility is there.

Please suggest a good practice and optimum way.

Comment: You can't have more than one package name per directory.  Can you give me a sample of what the function names would be in each of those files and I can try to give you an example of how I would organize it.  I don't typically end up with a "lib" folder any more.  It's simple to non-descript and isn't helpful when looking at your imports directory as to what is going to be available to you .  Package names tend to be important for not just organization, but clarity of purpose as well.

Comment: Please do not use imports of the form ./foo. Place code that is semantically connected into a common directory. A package can be composed of multiple files. Please use proper English.

Comment: @CoryLaNou You CAN have more than once package name per directory, you just won't be able to use `go build`. You'd have to write a custom makefile which isn't... particularly recommended when the other option is just 1 directory = 1 package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the "[Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names)" documentation on golang.org:

> Another convention is that the package name is the base name of its source directory;

Comment: The one place where I've seen multiple packages in the same folder is when doing black-box testing (eg. package validator and package validator_test).